# Is it possible for individual listviewitems selected, pointerover and pressed states to be controlled by the data bound item

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm currently trying to style a `ListView` so each of the items inside it can control their own background color, PointerOver, Pressed and Selected states.

I have figured out that I can set the Background of the `ListViewItem` to `Transparent` and let the `DataTemplate` for my item control the Background. But what I'm struggling with is the `VisualStates` of the `ListViewItem`. They just won't seem to style correctly.

What I've tried so far is so far is putting my `Binding` code for the colors inside the `Style` for the `ListViewItem` like so:

NOTE: Code has been cut down for brevity, `ListViewItem` style taken from the Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setters.../>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder">
                    <!-- ContentPresenter etc in here -->
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding AccentColour}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </VisualState>
                            <!-- More Visual States-->
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However this doesn't work and I assume it has something to do with the `ListViewItem` not knowing the `DataContext` for the `Binding`.

My item is just a basic class to hold info like the text associated with the item and the colors the for Background and the States.

```
public class BasicItem {
    // Constructor etc

    public SolidColorBrush AccentColour { get; set; }
    // More Colours
}
```

Another approach I had considered was creating `AttachedProperties` for the Colors on the ListViewItem. Only issue is I'm not sure how I would bind to them.

Anyone have any idea if it's possible for the Item to control its States in this way, any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using data templates or ListViewItem directly?

Comment: A combination of both. I use the DataTemplates to put the info from my class into the item. Then I have been using the ListViewItem for the styling of the states like pointerover, pressed and selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Another approach I had considered was creating AttachedProperties for
>   the Colors on the ListViewItem. Only issue is I'm not sure how I would
>   bind to them.

You are right about using *AttachedProperties* and this is how it can be done.

**Step *1*. Define your attached properties**

```
public static Brush GetPointerOverBackground(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (Brush)obj.GetValue(PointerOverBackgroundProperty);
}
public static void SetPointerOverBackground(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
{
    obj.SetValue(PointerOverBackgroundProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty PointerOverBackgroundProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PointerOverBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(YourStaticClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

**Step *2*. Define default values for your attached properties**

```
<Setter Property="local:YourStaticClass.PointerOverBackground" Value="LightBlue" />
```

**Step *3*. Use attached properties in your Visual States**

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding local:YourStaticClass.PointerOverBackground}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</VisualState>
```

**Step *4*. Create an Interface that defines all the brushes**

The reason of doing this is so we can later cast the object (i.e. `BasicItem`) bound to each template to this *Interface*, without the need of knowing its concrete type. Of course your `BasicItem` should implement this *Interface*.

```
public interface ISupportListViewItemBrushes
{
    SolidColorBrush PointerOverBrush { get; set; }
```

**Step *5*. Create a `Behavior` responsible for assigning `Brush`es to `ListViewItem`s**

This is where everything comes together. First we will need to install the [XAML Behavior Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/). After that, create a `Behavior` called `SupportListViewItemBrushesBehavior` and make it only attachable to a `ListView`.

```
public class SupportListViewItemBrushesBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
```

`ListView` has an event called `ContainerContentChanging` where we have access to each `ListViewItem` and its underlying `Item` (i.e. `BasicItem`/`ISupportListViewItemBrushes`) object. Finally, we just use the `SetAttachedPropertyName` method to assign the corresponding `Brush` to the `ListViewItem` like below

```
private void OnContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.InRecycleQueue && 
        args.ItemContainer is ListViewItem container && 
        args.Item is ISupportListViewItemBrushes brushes)
    {
        Helper.SetPointerOverBackground(container, brushes.PointerOverBrush);
    }
}
```

That's all!

---

Note we had to create the `Behavior` here because UWP doesn't support `FindAncestor` binding yet. Alternatively, rather than using *attached properties* and a `Behavior`, you can extend `ListView`/`ListViewItem` to achieve the same result.

I have included a small sample [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/DynamicListViewItemColorsRepo) for your reference. And here's the end result. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: I knew there had to be some way to do it via AttachedProperties but I couldn't get my head around it. Thanks so much, this is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [StyleSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.styleselector) that chooses the ListViewItem style you want for a given item, and set it as the [ItemContainerStyleSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemContainerStyleSelector) on your ListView.

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately, the items are being synced via a webservice. This is to allow the items colours to be changed via a web interface and also for new colours to be added at any time. Creating a style for every new colour that is added would be mean having to release a new version of the app so users can see the new colours.